# Normalizing Unix file paths by removing dot links and repeated slashes

Tags: c++, c, unix

What is a good method for normalizing Unix file paths (i.e., for removing dot links and repeated slashes)?
I neither need nor want symlink resolution.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. Please choose a language.

Comment: What do you want? `///usr/bin/../tmp/.././../../lib/openssh/./` mapped to `/lib/openssh` (or perhaps `/../lib/openssh`), based solely on textual manipulation?  Or do you want it mapped to `/usr/bin/../tmp/../../../lib/openssh`?  The second path mapping still traverses any symlinks, so it is arguably safer.

Comment: @Olaf Both tags mean I don't care, and I don't need to care, because either should work with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Not necessarily. As I wrote: C is not C++. They are **different languages which similar syntax, but sometimes subtle differences for the same syntax even.

Comment: Calls to compiled C code from C++  generally work most of the time all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About the no-link-resolution prerequisite:

- it makes things more complicated (because otherwise you could just use [stdlib's realpath()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html).
- it will break paths that contain links. For instance, `a/b/../foo` is **not** the same as `a/foo` if `b` is a symlink. Example:

  ```
  a
  ┣ b (symlink to c/d)
  ┣ c ┳ d
  ┃   ┗ foo
  ┗ foo
  ```

  In this case, `a/b/../foo` is actually `a/c/foo`, while a purely text-based normalization will incorrectly think it is `a/foo`.

Are you really sure you want that?

If you do, then you should handle all of those:

- Empty string (just return '.').
- Multiple initial slashes: 1 or 2, keep as is, more than that, cut down to 1. That is, `/a` and `//a` remain untouched, but `///a` and `////a` become `/a`. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and) for an explanation.
- Empty bits (`a//b`) should get removed.
- Dot bits (`a/./b`) should get removed.
- And now the fun part: double-dots.

  - The basic idea is they remove the preceding bits. `a/../b` → `a/b`.
  - But if they go upwards all the way to an initial slash, they should be removed. For instance `/../a` → `/a`. And `/a/../../../b` → `/b`.
  - And if they go upwards all the way to no initial slash, additional ones should be kept. For instance `../a` → `../a`. And `a/../../../b` → `../../b`.

If suggest you look at the normpath implementation in [python lib](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/posixpath.py). Granted, it's python, but the algorithm is very readable.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I might be dealing with paths to/through potentially nonexisting objects, so a partially normalizing realpath would be ideal, but I guess I'll simply normalize what can be normalized without FS information (consecutive slashes, './') and follow that with an attempted `realpath` call, which will either succeed or not.

Comment: (This is for a syscall-based dependency tracker--requests for nonexisting files still create a dependency and the dependencies should be somewhat normalized and deduplicated)

Comment: Makes sense. You should probably mention somewhere in the doc of your code that dependencies are not allowed to have symlinks in them. Shouldn't be needed anyway and will avoid the main pitfalls.